# Explanation needed on "client side" JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

In the past 2 hours i was looking for a deep insight on how JSF works. I read many good explanations, but every story was only about the JSF lifecycle on the SERVER, however i'm curious about the client side. Better spoken, i'm curious how the client browser will create the appropriate http request when the user interacts with the app. Btw JSF noobie here, so as far as i understand the picture, JSF is a server side MVC framework, OK.

- when the client enters a url in the browser, like somedomain.com/landingpage the server side framework accross some "building" steps produces html out of JSF pages. That's clear. So the end user will be served with a html page with optionally css and/or javascript.
- then the user is able to make some interaction, say, to fill up a form and submit it. When he/she submits the form the browser is creating a POST request to the server with the data. The request here was made by the browser because of the implementation/specification of a html form. The server gets this requests, bakes something and responds with a view (a.t.m i doesn't care about the server part)
- Anther example: We have a button, and i want this button to generate some dynamic content on the page, say clicking on the button should create two new divs on the page. So in the browser, clicking on the button a click event has been created. I'm curious in what will trigger here the request to the server to serve back a new page/view with the new content? (I know AJAX could do the job, but i'm asking for the default behavior here).

I asked one of my friends, and he said, that on JSF side we provide an actionListener on that button, and in the actionListener we define a bean method to be triggered for execution upon the click event. That's clear again. But what will create the request on client side? Some hidden JavaScript code? Or what?

So generally, i don't understand JSF's client side request-triggering methods. And i'm curious about them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to find out is to prepare some easy example and check it out. Or even use some example from tutorial.

Yes, on client side there is generated JavaScript code by JSF. This JS will prepare new request. It is kind of wrapper over standard submit button. Even when you have  markup in your JSF. There is  tag generated however href attribute is there ignored since there is function in onclick event which prepare and sends new request. So on the client side there is a JavaScript code generated from JSF.

If you won't use any  tag in any appropriate place in your JSF (example here: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-ajax-hello-world-example/) Whole document will be regenerated as you told so.

Answer (score 0):

> So generally, i don't understand JSF's client side request-triggering
>   methods. And i'm curious about them.

All requests are made through the **[HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)** communication/protocol system and are auto-managed by the client/browser. For your info, **HTTP** itself is encapsulated into **[TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol)**. The code that is generated on the client side is purely a mix of **[HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML)**, **[CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets)**, and **[JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)**, which is understandable by standard web browsers. There is no **[Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29)** code at all on the client side, no matter what server side framework you use.

Comment: I think you misread my question... :(
> _All requests are made through the HTTP communication/protocol system and are auto-managed by the client/browser_
Something need to trigger that request, and i want to know what is _that_ :)

Comment: @Jim-Y What trigger the requests are your actions on links, inputs like buttons, text fields, etc, and the actions triggered by some JavaScript functions (if any). All those events are captured by the browser and processed accordingly.

Comment: Yes, my idea was that the JSF framework also contains some JavaScript code, which will be sent down to the client, which -for example- will get the click event on buttons and start a request to the server in the background. Are there any official docs about them? The reason i want to know is that i want a better comparision between full client side frameworks, like Ember/Angular/Flux and full server side frameworks, like JSF. Thanks the answers